# How to add a private external dependency/jar from a gitlab maven repo to a google cloud data flow job

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Using the filesToStage option, can we add a dependency which is available on a private gitlab maven repository? If so, how can the token be specified in this option which will be needed to access the  dependency from the private repo.

If it is not possible to use filesToStage option to add a private external dependency to the data flow job then what are the other approaches that can be used to achieve this.

Comment: You Can install jar files from the local file system in your local repository as part of your build.

Comment: how do you build the pipeline? I guess you have your pom.xml file declaring your private repository? And when you run mvn install, the JAR is downloaded, right? Beam should be able to pick up that JAR from your classpath, and upload it

Comment: Is it not possible to get the dependency added from the private repo while the pipeline is running?

Comment: Beam's Java SDK gets the classpath from your local computer, and uploads all of that to GCP. This is almost the same as using `filesToStage`. How does this not fit your use case?

Answer (score 0):

When you build your pipeline, you would add your extra repository, and your extra dependency via your `pom.xml` or your `build.gradle` files.

Once you've added this extra dependency, you can run your pipeline as usual (via `mvn exec:java` or via `gradle run` or however you run your application - when the pipeline is constructed, Beam inspects the whole class path, and it uploads all of the files in it to be used in the workers' classpaths.

So you don't need to do anything other than define your dependency in `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`, and run your pipeline.

Let me know if this somehow won't fit your use case.